# Simplify Squared Expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I realize I haven't really dealt with simplifying non-linear expressions too much, and am just plain stuck. I'm having trouble with the algebra to simplify this expression:

$$\left(\frac{3}{8}r + \frac{1}{2}h\right)^2 - \left(\frac{3}{8}r\right)^2$$

To this one:

$$\frac{3r * 2h}{8}h$$

Could anyone briefly explain the rules to collect these terms together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT :

$$A^2-B^2=(A-B)(A+B).$$

Comment: Thanks, I realize there's a lot of algebraic identities I'm just not aware of and can search for the rest I need (if any) :)

Comment: @RandyGaul: You are welcome. Enjoy studying math!